# Customizing Beamer's Table of Contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I used the following standard beamer code to create a table of contents at the beginning of each subsection:

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

However, I want to customize the ToC of some subsections; something like:

> IF \subsectionname != "..." Then it's OK to show the standard ToC.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For specific subsections you may modify the behavior before they start: you could change `\AtBeginSubsection` locally. This means you could change that, for a subsection, but keep this change local by enclosing it within a group. For example, disabling `\AtBeginSubsection` and thus the subsection TOC:

```
\begingroup
\AtBeginSubsection{}
\subsection{No TOC}
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}
\endgroup
\subsection{Here's a TOC}
```

After the group ended, the globally by `\AtBeginSubsection` defined macro returns being active. The following subsections will show the TOC -  I tested it.

This works because `\AtBeginSubsection` uses `\def` to redefine internal macros, which works local, thus visible only inside a group, in contrary to `\gdef`.